# Push object to specific position of nested array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using tree view in my angular project and I want to push object to the specific position into array.

array

```
const TREE_DATA: TreeNode[] = [{"name":"Demo","id":"demo_1","children":[{"name":"Folder","id":"folder_1","children":[{"name":"File","id":1},{"name":"Doc","id":2}]},{"name":"Folder 2","id":"folder_2","children":[{"name":"doc file","id":3},{"name":"word","id":4}]}]},{"name":"Projects","id":"pro_1","children":[{"name":"Dir","id":"dir_1","children":[{"name":"ib","id":5},{"name":"Pro 2","id":6}]}]}]

const obj = { name: 'information', id: 50 }
```

and expected is

```
[{"name":"Demo","id":"demo_1","children":[{"name":"Folder","id":"folder_1","children":[{"name":"File","id":1},{"name":"Doc","id":2}]},{"name":"Folder 2","id":"folder_2","children":[{"name":"doc file","id":3},{"name":"word","id":4}]}]},{"name":"Projects","id":"pro_1","children":[{"name":"Dir","id":"dir_1","children":[{"name":"ib","id":5},{"name":"Pro 2","id":6}, { name: 'information', id: 50 }]}]}]
```

How can I push the object to specific place using Id into the array.

Comment: How are you planning on using the `id` ? in your expected result you just pushed that obj to the end of the array with no apparent reason.

Comment: yes @EvgenyKolyakov I can push any where in nested array using the `id`.

Comment: The question is not clear, how would I know the index, where I am going to push the object? And how "id" is going to tell me about the index?

Comment: @DanteDX If I say position instead of index then can I do using `id`?

Comment: there are two children property, one inside object, in nested inside an object, in which one you want to push the new object. This is not a hard problem to solve. But you structure of data should be clear. Use one property name at a time and you can edit your question

Comment: @DanteDX it should push inside the children of respective `id' and if there has no children the it should not push.

Comment: But which "id" each children property has another "children" and "id" nested inside it

Comment: @DanteDX I can pass any `id` like if I pass id `folder_2` then it should push inside that children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanteDX, I was looking something like below code, maybe my question was not cleared so you did not answered me ,

```
private search(items: TreeNode[], term: string): any[] {
        return items.reduce((acc: TreeNode[], item: TreeNode) => {
            if (this.contains(item.name, term)) {
                acc.push(item);
            } else if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
                let newItems = this.search(item.children, term);
                if (newItems.length > 0) {
                    acc.push({ ...item, children: newItems });
                }
            }
            return acc;
        }, []);
    }

    private contains(text: string, term: string): boolean {
        return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
```